# Creating a table like structure in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, download, tabular

I am making a download manager in python..
I want to create a table like structure with multiple columns and rows to show:

Download name, download status (paused/downloading), download size and other information interactively.

Can anyone give me ideas on how to create a table-like structure where I can easily add the data mentioned above?

Comment: A simple solution would be write to a file, one line per row.

Comment: When *what* is closed? The entire program, or just the window that is displaying your table?

Comment: marcadian- Thanks for your reply! :) but how can i display in a table?
@wesley baugh when the entire program is closed...at least it can be filled up again automatically

Comment: Fixed...I have found my paradise with a multilistbox widget:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52266-multilistbox-tkinter-widget/

Answer (score 3):

The ttk treeview widget allows you to have multiple columns. For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk # python 2.7
import ttk
...
root = tk.Tk()
...
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, ...)  
tree.configure(columns=('size', 'modified', 'owner'))
...
tree.insert('', 'end', text='item 1', values=('20k','yesterday', 'kilgore trout'))
```

For more information see http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing - you're talking about data structure and persistence then about list box (GUI stuff...)

wrt/  the data structure and persistence part a "table like" structure with "rows and columns" is easily modeled as a list of ducts or list of tuples. For the perstitance part you can serialize your list as json and write it to a file or write it as CSV ( using the stdlib CVS package) or use a SQL db.

Comment: edited the post... I just need a table structure where i can display the information mentioned above: Download name, download status(paused/downloading),download size

Comment: and i should be able to select the items in the table too...like a curselection for a listbox